# Make sure + subject or object

Tags: word-usage

> 1) My staff will do their best to make sure I enjoy in my stay.
>
> 2) My staff will do their best to make sure me enjoy in my stay.

Which pronoun should I choose after "make sure", subject or object?

Answer (score 1):

After the ***"make sure"***, you need to choose a subject because it has to be:

> **"make sure (that)" + *a complete sentence***

for the whole sentence to be complete. Using your example sentences, it should be:

> My staff will do their best to make sure (that) I enjoy my stay.

But to me, ***"my"*** staff making sure that ***"I"*** enjoy my stay sounds a bit odd. I think it needs be something like:

> The staff at the hotel will do their best to make sure (that) I enjoy
>   my stay there.

Comment: May I know the reason for inserting "there" in your last sentence as we don't where the person is staying.

Comment: My apology for the unnecessary insertion...  As you said, we don't know where the person of the subject is staying, but I assumed that person of the subject obviously knows where he/she is staying at, plus I used the "the" before hotel which kind of specifies a hotel, so I thought it wouldn't be wrong to insert the "there" at the end of this sentence...

Comment: Just for a clarification I am asking, if the person is staying at the hotel, can I delete "the" from the sentence?

Comment: Sure. Go ahead:-)